# Is there a function to return the last View that has been returned in MVC .Net Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult, .net-4.8

I want my webpage to be multilingual. That's why I created a Button that changes a session variable to for example fr (French). It's accomplished by an action result that changes the session variable. Now I am not sure what the action result should return so I am going to get to the same page as I was before. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found a way to do it myself, if I use this in my ActionResult the page refreshes and my language is changed.

```
return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
```

By using this you just reload the page that was loaded before, so when the variable for the language has been changed by my action controller it pulls the right textes out of my Database and by reloading it uses them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not how you describe.

What you can do is set the language as a parameter in your query, either as a regular query parameter (http://example.com/page?lang=kr) or using URL rewriting (http://example.com/kr/page) and use the parameter in the view to render the correct language.

And when you get to writing the language changes links, you use an action link like normal, but you overwrite the language parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1 : Use same concept of return url using query string that used to redirect user back to the same page after login

Way 2 : use ajax request to change language and on success just make reload

Way 3 : add language to url